# Wrong calculation UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, servo

I've a joystick and a servo connected to my UNO, but for some reason my calculations keep on being wrong? I'm trying to calculate how the rotation should be of my servo (Tower Pro 9g, max value of 180 I think) with my Joystick (Keyes_SJoys, max value of 1023 on any axis) and example would be:

y = 500;
servo.write(y * 180 / 1023); // should equal to 87.97, but in reality it's 24?

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo;
int d2 = 2;
int a0 = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  servo.attach(d2);
}

void loop() {
  int y = analogRead(a0);
  Serial.print("y: "); Serial.println(y);

  servo.write(y * 180 / 1023);
  Serial.println(y * 180 / 1023);

  delay(100);
}
```

PS. It's a Robotale UNO; I don't know if that makes any difference or not, but.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing is a common pitfall.
You are probably expecting floating point calculations, but what you are writing are only integer ones.

Try with:  y * 180. / 1023.   (notice the dots).

This will work only with constants.

To make it work with anything, use a cast:  y * 180 / (float) 1023

Happy hacking.

Comment: Awesome, this worked, thanks! (Just had to cast evertyhing)

Comment: Please select the answer as correct, if it helped.

Comment: One cast should be sufficient.

Comment: Oh, yea... But for some reason casting didn't work on `1023`, but it did on `180`. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting completely the wrong value (not just losing the decimal portion) is because of a problem called *integer overflow*.

Because the Arduino is an 8-bit device the default integer size is double that.  That means that an integer value can store 16 bits, and when signed that's -32768 to 32767.

Any calculations, unless you specify otherwise, have to fit into that range.  If you take your calculation step by step you will see how it works:

```
500 * 180 = 90,000
```

Represented in Hexadecimal (for ease of demonstration) 90,000 is 0x15F90.  That is 17 bits (4 bits per digit, the left hand is just one bit since it's only the value 1), and 17 is more than the maximum 16 allowed.  So we have to "overflow" that value and discard the lefthand-most digit to keep it at 16 bits.  So we end up with 0x5F90.

0x5F90 in decimal is 24464.  Now we divide that by 1023 and we get:

```
24464 / 1023 = 23.914
```

Because it's integers we have no decimal portion of it, so that just ends up as the 23 that you are seeing.

Solutions?  Change the data type.

As @IgorStoppa has pointed out you can use floating point values which gives you big values and the decimal portion.  As long as one value in your sum is floating point all the values will be. This is known as *promotion*.  There's numerous ways you can force floating values:

1. Represent your literals as a floating point value - that means adding a decimal place. You could have (as Igor shows) things like `1023.`, but I find that a little obscure.  It's better to explicitly show a decimal value since it's obvious what it is then, such as `y * 180.0 / 1023.0`.
2. Use a floating point *literal suffix*.  You can add certain letters after a number to describe what that number is.  `f` is for floating point: `y * 180f / 1023f`.

Floating point is quite heavy weight though and can cause your program to get bigger than you'd like.  If you're not interested in the decimal portion you can instead use *long* variables.  The best way to do that is with the *long* literal suffix `L`:  `y * 180L / 1023L`

*Promotion* means that all the variables are *promoted* to the size of the biggest variable (not greatest value, the variable with the largest storage space).  Long and Float are both 32 bits in size, so using either of those will force the other values to both be *promoted* to equivalent types.